# How to make bootstrap not overriding my specific style?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a html menu with specific CSS styles. This works fine until I add Bootstrap reference in header :

***Added Link***

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Adding this bootstrap reference makes the dropdown menu File not working anymore...
(Btw bootstrap has been added for other purpose : DataTables... but that's not the point).

What is my mistake ?

Help needed.

Thanks.

***Code without bootstrap***

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.bg-img {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("Dedale.jpg");
  /* min-height: 380px; */
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  /* Needed to position the navbar */
  /* position: relative; */
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  /* color: white; */
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.navbar a.active {
  /* background-color: #2196F3; */
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* Section SearchContainer */

.search-container {
  float: right;
}

.search-container button {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search-container button:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}


/* Input Zone */

.navbar input[type=text] {
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="navbar bg-img">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">File
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Open</a>
      <a href="#">Close</a>
      <a href="#">Quit</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***Code with bootstrap***

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.bg-img {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("Dedale.jpg");
  /* min-height: 380px; */
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  /* Needed to position the navbar */
  /* position: relative; */
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  /* color: white; */
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.navbar a.active {
  /* background-color: #2196F3; */
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* Section SearchContainer */

.search-container {
  float: right;
}

.search-container button {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search-container button:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}


/* Input Zone */

.navbar input[type=text] {
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="navbar bg-img">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">File
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Open</a>
      <a href="#">Close</a>
      <a href="#">Quit</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you write your css in a second css file? try to add first bootstrap and then your css.

Comment: No matter the place of bootstrap reference. Tried the 2 positions... To answer the first question, my css style is actually in a specific file, but I made the snippet to have in one.

Comment: You can either: 1) Increase the specificity of your CSS selectors (either match or exceed Bootstraps), 2) download the SASS and create a custom build that omits the offending components. **Note:** For #1, your CSS selectors will need to **undo** anything Bootstrap has set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dropdown` class which you are using in your code is default class of bootstrap. So it works when the bootstrap library is not added. And when you add the bootstrap library your `dropdown` class get clashed with bootstrap class. Change the name of `dropdown` class to some other class.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#dropdowns

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you use `position: absolute;` in `.dropwdown-content` and that positions the item absolutely to its first explicitly positioned parent. Bootstrap changes the position of the parent `.dropdown` to `relative`, and that changes the first positioned parent to `.dropdown`

**Solution:** change the `.dropdown-content` position to `fixed`; so `.dropdown-content` will be positioned related to the browser window.

A working example:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.bg-img {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("Dedale.jpg");
  /* min-height: 380px; */
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  /* Needed to position the navbar */
  /* position: relative; */
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  /* color: white; */
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.navbar a.active {
  /* background-color: #2196F3; */
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* Section SearchContainer */

.search-container {
  float: right;
}

.search-container button {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search-container button:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}


/* Input Zone */

.navbar input[type=text] {
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="navbar bg-img">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">File
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Open</a>
      <a href="#">Close</a>
      <a href="#">Quit</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```